# Items max height depends on max contents item

Tags: html, css

I have a group of items with news and i want the height of every item to be the same height as the maximum-content item. I want to change my fixed height to dynamic.

```
.article-3 {
   `text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    max-width: 235px;
    height: 335px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
`}
```

Comment: You can remove the `height` style from this. Or assign `height: auto` to this. That will work I guess.

Comment: With height:auto, every item get the height of its own content.

Comment: why not use flexbox ? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Maybe an `html` sample could help understanding your problem

Comment: `display: table-cell` instead of `block` will give your boxes uniform height while placing them left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use display flex

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.article-3 {
  border: 1px solid coral;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 article-3"> 
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" > 
      <span>some text</span> 
      <h4>some text</h4> 
    </a> 
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 article-3"> 
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" > 
      <span>
        some more text some more text
        some more text some more text
        some more text some more text
        some more text some more text
        some more text some more text
      </span> 
      <h4>some more text</h4> 
    </a> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: But is it a way to make it responsive?

Comment: in what way? You want the blocs to return to new line ?

Comment: When i am in mobile, it is like a block and my columns wont move the way i want ( the columns i have in the container i mean, col-xs-12 for example)

Comment: you're using bootstrap ?

Comment: <div class="row">            
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 article-3">
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" >
   <img src="#" class="img-responsive" align="center" />
   <span>some text</span>
   <h4>some text</h4>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 article-3">
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" >
   <img src="#" class="img-responsive" align="center" />
   <span>some more text</span>
   <h4>some more text</h4>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
and more 2 rows in the same way

Comment: I updated my answer. You should add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container (the row in your case)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by `grid` technique like following:

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div style="background-color:#F00">
    fasdfads fad
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:#960">
    fadsfadsfads<p>fadfdasfds</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:#0C3">
    afadsfads
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can i use it for vertical height?

Comment: @NikosSimaioforidis what's *vertical* height? Is there some sort of *horizontal* height?

Comment: Sorry I was got wrong your question, I thought you trying to achieve every row equal height vertically. So if column then you can easily do that by flex.